# wp_enqueue_script won't load in header?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Read up on this, and I believe I'm doing everything right. Everything is getting loaded in the footer. Here is my code:

```
function load_kenburns() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
wp_register_script( 'kenburns', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bannerscollection_kenburns.js', '', '', false);
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js', '', '', false);
wp_register_script( 'jquery-touch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js', '', '', false);
wp_register_script( 'kbsettings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/kenburnsettings.js', '', '', false);
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_kenburns' );
```

I then enqueue the script on the page I need it.

```
<?php
 wp_enqueue_script( 'kbsettings' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'kenburns' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-touch' );
?>
```

Any ideas why they won't load in the head? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write wp_enqueue_script in wp_enqueue_scripts action

```
function load_kenburns() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_register_script( 'kenburns', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bannerscollection_kenburns.js', '', '', false);
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js', '', '', false);
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-touch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js', '', '', false);
    wp_register_script( 'kbsettings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/kenburnsettings.js', '', '', false);
     wp_enqueue_script( 'kbsettings' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'kenburns' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-touch' );
    }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_kenburns' );
```

Comment: Then I'm confused on how to to get the scripts to load on a certain page? I need them to only load on the home page.

Comment: if(is_page('page_slug')){ //code stuff } use this in load_kenburns function. page_slug change with certain page slug.